# Select all items with sum of fields in specified range

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have simple table:

```
file_size file_id file_time  
   1        1         19  
   2        2         20  
   3        3         21  
   4        4         22  
   5        5         23
```

I want to find such item that all items with less file_time has the sum of file_size in predefined range.
I written next query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table AS D0 WHERE 
(SELECT TOTAL(file_size) FROM test_table AS D1 WHERE
D1.file_time <= D0.file_time ORDER BY file_id)
BETWEEN 1 AND 9
```

This query get correct results:

```
   1        1         19  
   2        2         20  
   3        3         21
```

But this query does not work if needed items has the same file_time field:

```
file_size file_id file_time  
   1        1         20  
   2        2         20  
   3        3         20  
   4        4         20  
   5        5         20
```

The desired result for this data is:

```
   1        1         20  
   2        2         20  
   3        3         20
```

The file_id field is unique.
What is wrong in my SQL-query?

The code to create test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (file_size INT, file_id INT, file_time INT)
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(1,1,20)
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(2,2,20)
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(3,3,20)
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(4,4,20)
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(5,5,20)
```

Comment: What is your expected result? It's not clear to me.

Comment: Find all the old (by file_time) items with sum of file_size in specified range. My original query is OK, while file_time is unique.

Comment: It works fine form me, exactly as you wanted in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't consider `file_time` as a single column in your query, since you want to consider the column `file_id` either. You should use the pairs of `file_time` and `file_id` and you should compare them lexicographically as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_table AS D0
WHERE (

  SELECT TOTAL( file_size ) 
  FROM test_table AS D1
  WHERE D1.file_time < D0.file_time
  OR (
    D1.file_time = D0.file_time
    AND D1.file_id <= D0.file_id
  )
  ORDER BY file_time, file_id DESC
)
BETWEEN 1 
AND 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood but I think

```
-- sum of file sizes between 1 and 7 with the lowest time
SELECT SUM(test.file_size) AS sum_file_size, test.file_time
 FROM test
 WHERE (test.file_time = (SELECT TOP 1 test.file_time 
                           FROM test 
                           ORDER BY file_time))
 AND (test.file_size BETWEEN 1 AND 9)
 GROUP BY test.file_time;

-- sum of file sizes per time `group`
SELECT SUM(test.file_size) AS sum_file_size, test.file_time,
 FROM test
 WHERE (test.file_size BETWEEN 1 AND 7)
 GROUP BY test.file_time
 ORDER BY test.file_time;
```

Comment: Your query does not work even for unique file_time (19,20,21,22...)

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't work i.e. errors or that it's not doing what you want?

Comment: No errors (sqlite not support TOP - it replaced by LIMIT). The result of query are wrong. The working query:    SELECT SUM(file_size) AS sum_file_size, file_time, file_id FROM first
 WHERE (file_time <= (SELECT file_time FROM first ORDER BY file_time LIMIT 1)) AND (first.file_size BETWEEN 1 AND 7) GROUP BY first.file_time;. For pairs file_size,file_time - {{1,18},{2,19},{3,20},{4,21},{5,22}} i want to get {{1,18},{2,19},{3,20}} as result. But your query return {1,18}.

Comment: sorry are you saying that your query is working as you'd expect and the question is answered?

Comment: My query work fine on datas where file_time are unique. But not work if some of first items has the same file_time field.

Comment: Have you tried running your query on one of my tables? It does not work on first my table (with unique file_time) and does not work on second table (file_time is same for all items).

Comment: Hi, I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve see my updated answer.